# Problema con streamreader - C#

Tags: c#

Estoy practicando con streamreader en C# y tuve el siguiente problema

```
 System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\vertices.txt");
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if ((line[0].ToString()!="#")&(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)==false))
                {

                        cont = cont + 1;
                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                }
            }
        }
```

En la linea del IF me tira un error out range en line[0].tostring no entiendo por que siendo que el primer caracter tiene un valor en este caso '#' y de hecho este problema esta arreglado cuando anido las condiciones en dos IF no tira el error index out range el problema es que nose por que no puede estar en un solo IF y por que tira el error index out range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos problemas en tu condición:

Por un lado deberías utilizar el operador `&&` en lugar de `&`. Primero deberías comprobar que la línea no está vacía y, si es así, comprobar que el primer carácter no sea `#`. El operador `&` siempre evalúa las dos expresiones, el operador `&&` únicamente evalúa la segunda si la primera es cierta.

Por otro lado el orden debería ser el inverso: primero comprobar que la línea no esté vacía y segundo que el primer carácter no sea el buscado.

Algo así:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line[0].ToString()!="#")
```

Comment: Si tambien lo habia arreglado de esa manera, pero no entendi por que el orden y sobre todo porque el error de indexoutrange, me podrias explicar?

Comment: Tal y como lo tenías en el momento en que llegase una fila vacía lo primero que haría sería intentar comprobar que el primer carácter no fuera `#`. Como el primer carácter no existe (la fila está vacía) da un error.

Comment: Ahh oks lo que me decis es cuando comprueba que la fila esta vacia y pasa a preguntar line[0] dado q la linea esta vacia es index out range no?

Comment: Eso es. Al no haber ningún carácter, no existe carácter en la posición 0.